# Raster to polygon using R

Tags: python, gdal, r

I am trying to convert a raster object to a polygon object using R but I am running into some problems using my Windows 7 machine.

I originally tried to use `rasterToPolygons (package: raster)` but it kept crashing my computer so I opted to use the R port of `gdal_polygonize` with directions found [here](http://johnbaumgartner.wordpress.com/2012/07/26/getting-rasters-into-shape-from-r/)

However, I cannot get this to work because I receive the error message:

```
ImportError: No module named site
Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv) : 
  Cannot open file
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"python" "C:/OSGeo4W64" "C:\Users\RDCERWAW\AppData\Local\Temp\1\RtmpGgkaqN\file1ddc84b56b5.asc" -f "ESRI Shapefile" "C:\Users\RDCERWAW\AppData\Local\Temp\1\RtmpGgkaqN\file1ddcbde726a.shp"' had status 1
```

The problem seems to be with the `system2()` call. When I try to use it to call Python, I get the error

```
ImportError: No module named site
Warning message:
running command '"python" print hello' had status 1
```

(The above is probably incorrect, but I can't find out how to test the call to python using R)

Gdal is installed at `C:/OSGeo4W64` and the Path to both `gdal_polygonize` and Python are in my PATH. I can run `gdal_polygonize` from the console by typing

```
gdal_polygonize C:\GIS\temp.tif if 'ESRI Shapefile' C:\GIS\temp.shp
```

---

I ran the gdal_polygonizeR() function line by line and found out there were two problems. First, the raster that I was using as input had been created by cropping another raster and so the data source was a temporary file that no longer existed.

Secondly, the call to the directory for python (C:\OSGeo4W64\bin) was not able to import gdal, so I had to install gdal separately from the OSGeo4W installation (not sure why) and then I was able to import gdal from within OSGeo4W.

Comment: What has this got to do with R? I would focus on that, you give no details on the crash, your computer, or the code.

Comment: The crash comes when I use rasterToPolygons() from the raster package. There are no messages within R, it is simply that R stops working. It appears to be a memory issue and others have also encountered  this problem.

Comment: When I parts of the function, the issue appears to be in the call to Python. The following codeystem2('python', args=(sprintf('"%1$s" "%2$s" -f "%3$s" "%4$s.shp"',
                                  pypath, rastpath, gdalformat, outshape)))

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of this problem, then we can understand what's going on (i.e. provide us with the .tif file you're trying to convert)

Comment: @user44796 You can edit your question with additional information you provided in the comments as well as code that folks can debug and examine

Comment: If its simply a memory exhaustion problem then a) get more memory b) downsample your raster c) chop your raster into overlapping tiles, polygonise and merge.

Comment: You are pretty scant on details. Perhaps there is a good reason that this particular raster is causing bad behavior in rasterToPolygons. Memory shortages do not commonly cause a crash so, it is concerning that rasterToPolygons is causing a computer crash. R is carefully constructed to avoid this and in looking at source this is just a function and not compiled code. Can you please provide some details about your raster (nrow, ncol, format, disk size, how is it being read in...)? As @Sapcedman suggested, have you tried a subset?

Comment: All. Sorry for the lack of details. I was focused on solving a problem (converting a raster to a polygon object) and so I stopped trying to get the rasterToPolygons() function to work since I finally got the uncompiled function gdal_polygonizeR to work.